# Building Razor view using foreach and switch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to recreate this in Razor with a foreach and switch and having difficulties. It seems that opening and closing DIVs cause issue in the Razor 
code and it keeps saying either I don't have a closing `}` on the `foreach (var questionBasicSection in Model.ToList())` or the `</div>` in the last case doesn't have a matching start tag.

I have tried using `<text></text>` tags around the `<div class="row mt5"> <!-- @question.QUESTION -->` tags but can't use it
around the ` tags.

Any ideas as to how to accomplish this?
Because the sections are different, it really has to be formatted this way...

**Here's the desired HTML output:**

```
<div class="row mt5"> <!-- Personnel -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label col-med-6" for="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ANSWER_FLOAT">a. Personnel</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].AnswerFloatString" class="form-control currencyMask amt" data-bind="textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE"
               data-pattern="currency" id="Personnel_Amount_Budgeted" type="text" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="4" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ID" value="200" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="False" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="9" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[1].AnswerFloatString" class="form-control percentMask" data-bind="textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE"
               data-pattern="percent" id="Personnel_Amount_Budgeted_Pct" type="text" value="" disabled />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[1].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[1].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="4" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[1].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[1].ID" value="201" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[1].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[1].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="False" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[1].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[1].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="9" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt5"> <!-- Equipment -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[2].AnswerFloatString" class="form-control currencyMask amt" data-bind="textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE"
               data-pattern="currency" id="Fringe_Benefits_Budgeted" type="text" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[2].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[2].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="4" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[2].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[2].ID" value="202" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[2].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[2].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="False" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[2].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[2].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="9" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].AnswerFloatString" class="form-control percentMask_2" data-bind="textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE"
               data-pattern="percent" id="Fringe_Benefits_Pct" type="text" value="" disabled />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="4" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].ID" value="203" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="False" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="9" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[4].AnswerFloatString" class="form-control percentMask" data-bind="textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE"
               data-pattern="currency" id="Fringe_Benefits_Budgeted_Pct" type="text" value="" disabled />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[4].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[4].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="4" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[4].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[4].ID" value="204" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[4].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[4].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="False" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[4].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[4].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="9" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt5"> <!-- Travel-->
    <div class="col-md-2">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[5].AnswerFloatString" class="form-control currencyMask amt" data-bind="textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE"
               data-pattern="currency" id="Travel_Budgeted" type="text" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[5].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[5].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="4" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[5].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[5].ID" value="205" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[5].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[5].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="False" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[5].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[5].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="9" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[6].AnswerFloatString" class="form-control percentMask" data-bind="textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE"
               data-pattern="percent" id="Travel_Budgeted_Pct"  type="text" value="" disabled />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[6].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[6].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="4" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[6].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[6].ID" value="206" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[6].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[6].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="False" />
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[6].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[6].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="9" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here's the Razor code:**

```
@foreach (var questionBasicSection in Model.ToList())
{
    @* doing some other stuff here *@
    foreach (var question in questionBasicSection.Questions)
    {
        var QuestionTitle = (question.DISPLAY_NAME != null?question.DISPLAY_NAME + " " + question.QUESTION: question.QUESTION);
        switch (question.QuestionIndex) 
        {
            case 200:
                <text><div class="row mt5"> <!-- @question.QUESTION --></text>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label col-med-6" for="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ANSWER_FLOAT">@QuestionTitle/label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth currencyMask amt",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
            case 201:
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth percentMask",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                break;
            case 202:
                <text><div class="row mt5"> <!-- @question.QUESTION --></text>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label col-med-6" for="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ANSWER_FLOAT">@QuestionTitle/label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth currencyMask amt",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
            case 203:
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth percentMask",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
            case 204:
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth percentMask",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                break;
            case 205:
                <text><div class="row mt5"> <!-- @question.QUESTION --></text>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label col-med-6" for="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ANSWER_FLOAT">@QuestionTitle/label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth currencyMask amt",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
            case 206:
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth percentMask",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the closing </div> tags on your col-md-xx divs. Actually, some of your cases are missing, some are OK, and some have an extra closing tag. Make each case self contained.

Comment: Look at the desired output, each case is actually part of a section, the closing `</div>` have to go in the right place. i.e case 200, and 201 make up 1 section, case 201, 202 and 203 make up another, and so forth.

Comment: Your code isn't taking advantage of any MVC features.  This could all be reduce to not using loops nor switch statements.  Also your views are doing logic on values, that is also not preferred.

Comment: Move your section <div> and </div> outside the question loops. Each question should have same number of <div> and </div>. Not sure the purpose of the <text> tags.

Comment: Take a look at the desired output Mr. Greene, each question may have the same number of `<div></div>` tags but each SECTION (Personnel, Equipment , Travel) has different number of questions..

Comment: Yeah, get it done it many times. Inside the section `foreach` start you section with a <div class="row mt5"> <!-- @question.QUESTION -->. Then do your question loop with the switch where each question enclosed in <div> </div>. Now after that loop close out the section </div>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier to show you in code:

```
@foreach (var questionBasicSection in Model.ToList())
{
    // New section start
    <div class="row mt5"><span>@question.QUESTION</span>

    @* doing some other stuff here *@
    foreach (var question in questionBasicSection.Questions)
    {
        var QuestionTitle = (question.DISPLAY_NAME != null?question.DISPLAY_NAME + " " + question.QUESTION: question.QUESTION);
        switch (question.QuestionIndex) 
        {
            case 200:
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label col-med-6" for="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ANSWER_FLOAT">@QuestionTitle/label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth currencyMask amt",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
            case 201:
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth percentMask",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
            case 202:
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label col-med-6" for="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ANSWER_FLOAT">@QuestionTitle/label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth currencyMask amt",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
            case 203:
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth percentMask",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
            case 204:
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth percentMask",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
            case 205:
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label col-med-6" for="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[0].ANSWER_FLOAT">@QuestionTitle/label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth currencyMask amt",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
            case 206:
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(q => question.AnswerFloatString, (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { id=question.QUESTION.Replace(' ', '_').Replace(".", String.Empty).Replace("=", String.Empty),
                                          name = "QuestionBasicSection.Questions[" + question.Index + "].AnswerFloatString", @class = "form-control floatwidth percentMask",
                                          data_bind = "textInput: sdto.DATE_INACTIVE", data_pattern = question.FORMAT_VALIDATION })
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" value="@question.ANSWER_DATA_TYPE" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].ID" value="@question.ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].IS_MULTI_ANSWER" value="@question.IS_MULTI_ANSWER.ToString()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[@question.Index].QUESTION_SECTION_ID" value="@question.QUESTION_SECTION_ID.ToString()" />
                    </div>
                break;
        }  // end of questions for section
    }  //end of section

    // Section end
    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@:` syntax for each line of partial HTML code:

```
@if (foo)
{
    @:</div>
}
```

However, I've still had issues with this when autoformatting on paste is enabled. As Razor re-evaluates the entire view and more often than not borks everything with improper indentation and not breaking lines like it should.

Probably your safest bet is to use `Html.Raw`:

```
@if (foo)
{
    @Html.Raw("</div>")
}
```

Now, it's not even HTML code anymore. It's just a string so Razor will ignore it entirely.